# cocos2d. How to create a popup modal dialog (with CCLayer)

Tags: dialog, cocos2d-iphone, popup, modal-dialog

I need to make a modal dialog(inherited from CCLayer) that is showing in the center of the main layer.
While it is showing, you can not press any other button outside the dialog.
Just like a normal modal window in MS Windows System.

The problem is that I can not figure out how to disable the mainlayer's touch events while the dialog is showing.

Any help would be aprreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set

```
self.isTouchEnabled = NO;
```

in the main layer while the popup is displayed. Then later set it back to YES.

Comment: I've tried to do this, but I can still click buttons, code follows 
`- (void)menuButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"clicked a button");
    [self setIsTouchEnabled:NO];
        
    CCLayerColor *colorLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(0, 0, 0, 255)];
    [colorLayer setOpacity:80];
    [self addChild:colorLayer];`

Comment: This doesnt work with menuitems, right? @zardon what method did you use?

Comment: Okey, so what I did was put a stretched ccmenuitemimage over the whole layer with opacity 0. I really couldn't get anything else to work, but this works perfectly. isTouchEnabled only seems to disable the ccTouch events

Comment: There is `isMouseEnabled`, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Cocos2d-x but can be adapted to Cocos2d too.

I've change setParent to:

```
virtual void setParent(CCNode* parent)
{
    CCLayerColor::setParent(parent);        

    if (parent)
    {
        saveTouchesRecursive(parent);

        for (unsigned int i=0; i<mSavedTouches.size(); i++)
        {
            CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->removeDelegate(mSavedTouches[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (unsigned int i=0; i<mSavedTouches.size(); i++)
        {
            CCStandardTouchDelegate* standardTouchDelegate =  dynamic_cast<CCStandardTouchDelegate*>(mSavedTouches[i]);
            CCTargetedTouchDelegate* targetedTouchDelegate =  dynamic_cast<CCTargetedTouchDelegate*>(mSavedTouches[i]);

            CCLayer* layer =  dynamic_cast<CCLayer*>(mSavedTouches[i]);

            if (layer)
            {
                layer->registerWithTouchDispatcher();
            }
            else if (standardTouchDelegate)
            {
                CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addStandardDelegate(mSavedTouches[i], 0);
            }
            else if (targetedTouchDelegate)
            {
                CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(mSavedTouches[i], 0,  false);
            }
            else
            {
                CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(mSavedTouches[i], 0,  false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And added the following recursive code to save the touch delegates so I can restore them when the dialog dismissed:

```
std::vector<CCTouchDelegate*> mSavedTouches;
void saveTouchesRecursive(CCNode* node)
{
    if (node != this)
    {    
        CCTouchDelegate* touchDelegate = dynamic_cast<CCTouchDelegate*>(node);
        if (touchDelegate)
        {
            CCTouchHandler* handler = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->findHandler(touchDelegate);

            if (handler)
            {
                mSavedTouches.push_back(touchDelegate);
             }
        }

        for (unsigned int i=0; i<node->getChildrenCount(); i++)
        {
            CCNode* childNode = dynamic_cast<CCNode*>(node->getChildren()->objectAtIndex(i));

            if (childNode)
            {
                saveTouchesRecursive(childNode);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```